# Failed to resolve config file, knex cannot determine where to generate migrations

Tags: database, path, migration, knex.js

I’m trying to migrate and seed in a certain directory(database dir).  But when I run:

`npx knex migrate:make testing_table`

it shows:

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received undefined
    at validateString (internal/validators.js:124:11)
```

Directory

- Main folder
- Client
- Server

  - Database

    - Migrations
    - Knexfile.js
  - Public
- Package.json
- etc.

What I've done is that I’ve moved the knexfile.js outside the database directory and into the main directory. It works and migrates, but it creates another migration folder in the main rather than creating a table in the current migration folder.

Here is the code:

connection:

```
const config = require('../db/knexfile')
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'
const connection = knex(config[env])

module.exports = connection
```

knex file:

```
module.exports = {
  development: {
    client: 'sqlite3',
    connection: {
      filename: './dev.sqlite3'
    },
    useNullAsDefault: true,
    // Getting SQlite to honour contraints
    pool: {
      afterCreate: (conn, cb) =>
        conn.run('PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON', cb)
    }
  },

  test: {
    client: 'sqlite3',
    connection: {
      filename: ':memory:'
    },
    useNullAsDefault: true,
    seeds: {
      directory: path.join(__dirname, 'tests/seeds')
    },
    migrations: {
      directory: path.join(__dirname, 'migrations')
    }
  },

  production: {
    client: 'sqlite3',
    connection: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
    pool: {
      min: 2,
      max: 10
    },
    migrations: {
      directory: path.join(__dirname, './server/db/migrations')
    },
    seeds: {
      directory: path.join(__dirname, './seeds')
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the question? ;-)

Comment: Apologize for not clarifying. How do you knex migrate tables from the specific directory?

Comment: I edited the post, hopefully, it would make more sense.

Comment: Take a look at `npx knex --help` and see if you can specify the config from outside of your source code.

Answer (score 1):

if you have moved the knexfile into Main Folder(as you've mentioned in the folder structure), you'll have to change the path of migrations directory as follows:-

```
test: {
client: 'sqlite3',
connection: {
  filename: ':memory:'
},
useNullAsDefault: true,
seeds: {
  directory: path.join(__dirname, 'tests/seeds')
},
migrations: {
  directory: path.join(__dirname, './Database/Migrations') //--Changed this line
}},
```